# Which version of pygame is right for me?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, package

I am trying to install pygame. But I am not sure which version is appropriate for me.

I am working on a Windows 10 AMD64 PC.

The version of Python that is installed, shows-

> Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

on typing `python` into the command prompt.

I can find the packages [here](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads/) and [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame).

But there are only items listed such as-

> - Download repository
> - pygame-1.9.2-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
> - pygame-1.9.2-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl
> - pygame-1.9.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
> - pygame-1.9.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
> - pygame-1.9.2-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl
> - pygame-1.9.2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

Now I have no idea which one of these is to get.

And, what are the differences among cp27, cp34 and cp35?

**Please help me choose my version.**

Comment: `pip install pygame` installs the correct version for your system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

normally you should just type  following command

```
py -m pip install pygame
```

On non windows system you just type

```
pip install pygame
```

and the correct file will be downloaded and installed.

The pip module will consult https://pypi.org to indentify the versions available and choses normally the right one